# best way to remove the span tags without removing the inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function to hide and show certain fields the problem is the labels are just text inside a td with the label id applied such as resolution_type_c_label. I cant hide the td itself because it breaks the table layout so I hide the text with innerwrap. What is the best to remove the span tags without removing the text when I want to show the fields.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    hide();

    function hide(){
        if($('#status').val() != 'Resolved') {

            $('#resolution_type_c').hide();
            $('#resolution_type_c_label').wrapInner('<span id="wrap1" style="display:none"></style>');

            $('#resolution_sub_c_label').wrapInner('<span id="wrap2" style="display:none"></style>');
            $('#resolution_sub_c').hide();

            $('#resolution_label').wrapInner('<span id="wrap3" style="display:none"></style>');
            $('#resolution').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#resolution_type_c').show();
            $('#resolution_sub_c').show();
            $('#resolution').show();
        }

    } */

    $('#status').on('change', function() {
        hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: Why remove the `spans`, is it messing with your layout?

Comment: Can you not just create the spans in the first place, and then just show/hide them as required?

Comment: $('#resolution_sub_c_label').unwrap(); - http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) and [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) wraps an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

courtesy @Spokey from his comments on post

```
$('span').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: i thought about unwrap but don’t you have to use it on an element? Inside my spans there is only text.

Comment: @user794846 `$('span').contents().unwrap();`